# C# search in a textfile words to a listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-webcontrol

I have an ASP.NET *ListBox* that displays a list of activites taken from a text file.  Now what I want to do is to search words, for example "hockey", entered by the user in a *TextBox* control, and display in the ListBox only the activities containing that search string.

Answer (score 2):

The question is vague enough, but considering information got from the post, I would say follow this pattern (a pseudocode):

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filepath)) 
 {

       while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
       {
           string fileLine = sr.ReadLine();
           if(fileLine .Contains("hockey"))
                 DisplayInListBox(fileLine );
       }
}
```

Something like this.

Comment: Looks like he already read data from a file since already bound it to a ListBox. Also code which mixed togethe file read operations an UI update looks not quite good from my point of view, why just not separate low-leve file-read functionality from UI stuff?

Comment: @sll: to be honest, not very clear.. cause in both cases he talks about `activites`

Answer (score 0):

pretty trivial I guess:

```
var items = //listBox1.Items;
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();

    foreach (object s in items)
    {
        if (s.ToString().Contains("hockey"))
            listBox1.Items.Add(s);
    }

    if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

The basic idea is to cache listbox's initial items, and clear it and then fill according to string typed in textbox.